# Does binary logging apply to ColumnStore?

Tags: mariadb, columnstore

When binary logging is enabled, does MariaDB's binary logging also record ColumnStore events, and not just InnoDB events?  For example, does it log an UPDATE made to a ColumnStore table row?

I've searched the MariaDB documentation and it doesn't mention whether binary logging applies only to some, but not all, storage engines.  Is binary logging independent of the storage engine used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the official documentation at [Overview of the Binary Log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/overview-of-the-binary-log/) (MariaDB | Knowledge Base) the first paragraph states:

> The **binary log contains a record of all changes to the databases**, both data and structure, as well as how long each statement took to execute. It consists of a set of binary log files and an index.

If you rummage through MariaDB's ColumnStore documentation you will eventually find the article labelled [ColumnStore Storage Architecture](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/columnstore-storage-architecture/) which in the last paragraph **Transaction Log** mentions:

> MariaDB ColumnStore supports logging committed transaction to the server's Binary Log.

## Your Question

> Is binary logging independent of the storage engine used?

Yes, following the documentation we have come full circle. Any changes to the data are logged; be it a normal storage engine or the new ColumnStore engine.